# How to skip a failed step in spark job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark job that mimics an issue I am trying to solve. My test spark job reads files from a HDFS location /tmp/input/ which has files 1.txt, 2.txt.....10.txt
Then it creates a dataframe and writes this dataframe to /tmp/output/. If for one random file for example 4.txt if I try writing it to a wrong output location it will fail, which is acceptable. But, rather the spark exits the context and the remaining files are not processed.

Is there a way in spark where it can fail gracefully for 4.txt, maybe log the message and then move on to reading and writing for the remaining files?

This is my code:

```
      inputFileList.foreach(i => {
        try {
          val df = spark.read.csv(s"${i}")
          // Writing to a wrong location should fail the spark job.
          if(count == 4) {
            df.write.format("csv").save(s"$wrongOutput/$count")
          }  else {
            df.write.format("csv").save(s"$output/$count")
          }
          count = count + 1
          println(s"Done: ${count}/${total}")
          println(s"Job ended: ${java.time.LocalDateTime.now()}")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `catch` or `except` block to catch the exception and allow the program foreach loop to continue.